# Exporting geotagged photos from Google Earth Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, google-maps, google-earth, google-maps-api

I have a project and I am assessing social media based landscape photographs. How can I download photos as point shapefile and export them from Google Earth Pro to ArcMap?

Comment: Are you interested in a point shapefile where each point represents a photo and each point attribute has a download link for that photo?

Comment: I am interested in both point shapefile and the photo. There should be a way to extract them. Nice to see your help again.

Answer (score 2):

In Google earth you can right click on the location of the image then save as

[image]

[image]

Once you are done with your photos, you save them in a folder in MyPlaces. You can give them the same names as the photos.Then right click on the folder name and select "Save Place As..."

[image]

Choose the KMZ or KML Format and load it to your software.

[image]

If your photos are Geotagged,  I would simply use GPSBabel to load the photos and export the EXIF info (the coordinates) as Shapefiles.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really helpful

Comment: .kmz files are working but when I download the photos and transfer it into shapefile via GPSBabel, the point had no georeference. By the way, is there any way to download photos from a specific bbox?